# GridView shows queried data but does not show all data when primary key is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, webforms

I am trying to display all Funder information inside a GridView and also be able to filter them. As of now, If I hardcode the `FunderId=somenumber` in the URL, it shows the data. But when data is null, it shows nothing, whereas the procedure is telling it to show all the data for every FunderId.

I am using this select stored procedure. If there is a specified `FunderId`, show the data for that `FunderId`. If there is no specified `FunderId`, show data for all Funders.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFunderId_Select]
    @FunderId int = NULL 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM vueFunders 
    WHERE ([FunderId] = @FunderId OR @FunderIdIS NULL) 
END
```

This is the aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFunderData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     DataSourceID="sdsFunders"
     ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
     CssClass="GridView"
     PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
     ShowFooter="true"
     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true"
     PageSize="20" AllowSorting="true"
     EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."">

            <Columns>
                <%--FnderId--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FunderId" SortExpression="FunderId">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFunderId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FunderId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <%--Money--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Money" SortExpression="Money">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMoney" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Money")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <%--BankName--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NameOfBank" SortExpression="NameOfBank">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNameOfBank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NameOfBank") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsFunders" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseLive %>"
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        SelectCommand="spFunderId_Select">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="FunderId" QueryStringField="FunderId" Type="Int32"/>
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FunderId" DbType="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Money" DbType="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NameOfBank" DbType="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Surely, If I comment out the `QueryStringParameter`, it displays all the data for all funders, but then you cannot filter it as you cannot query the `FunderId`. All help is appreciated!

Comment: is your stored procedure returning all data if FunderId IS NULL ? Have you checked this ?

Comment: Yeah if I run this in SSMS, it returns all data. DECLARE FunderId int = NULL SELECT  * FROM vueFunders WHERE ([FunderId] = FunderId OR FunderId IS NULL) END returns absolutely everything. This is so mind boggling

Comment: Also runs in SSMS if I declare FunderId = 4 or any actual FunderId, so it makes no sense to me why nothing is being displayed on the front end.

Comment: I am no ASP expert, but it appears that you are sending a 0 as the default value and not null.  If you run an extended event to trace what is getting sent to the server you can see what the proc is receiving as a parameter.

Comment: @JMabee I also tried that while debugging. Changed <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="WorkPeriodId" QueryStringField="WorkPeriodId" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>

Comment: @JMabee however If I run the profiler as you suggested, exec spFunders_Select @FunderId=5 is what is shown when I hardcode the Id into the url and send it. But nothing gets executed on start or if I hardcode the Id to be NULL.

Comment: So then while debugging, what was the actual value of @FunderID sent to the server? What did the trace say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  * FROM vueFunders WHERE (   @FunderId IS NULL OR  @FunderId = 0 OR [FunderId] = @FunderId )
```

Comment: This combined with  <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="WorkPeriodId" QueryStringField="WorkPeriodId" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/> fixed my issue. Thank you!